# how to modify a default route table in VPC

Tags: boto, amazon-vpc

I want to modify a route table which is by default created during creation of VPC using boto module. but i can't able to find out default route table id.
how should i do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `vpc-id`, a quick way is to grab the first (and only) route table after applying a filter for the target VPC:

```
import boto.vpc

conn=boto.vpc.connect_to_region("us-east-1")
route_tables = conn.get_all_route_tables(filters={'vpc-id': 'vpc-ABCD1234'})
route_table = route_tables[0]
```